# How can I create a button in this extension which opens up a specific view in the main app without using the action buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am setting up a notification content extension in IOS and would like to add a button which opens up a specific view in the main app.

I can do this through the action buttons (at the bottom) but would like to add a button to the exentsion view itself.

@IBAction func btn_openapp(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let mystring = "mydrop://" + String(campaign_id)
    self.extensionContext?.open(URL(string: mystring)!, completionHandler: nil)

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
{

    d_me["single"] = url.host

    print(url.host,url.scheme)
    if url.scheme == "mydrop://"
    {
        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let targerView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CampaignDetailViewController")
        rootViewController.pushViewController(targerView, animated: false)

    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share some code for better understand.

Comment: Hi Jan, please add a [MCVE] so that we may be able to answer your question more appropriately.

Comment: Here is the code from the app content extension and from the AppDelegate (in the app itself). However it does not open a specific view. What do I need to add to the code for it to open a specific view?

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
    {
        if url.scheme == "mydrop://"
        {
            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let targerView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CampaignDetailViewController")
            rootViewController.pushViewController(targerView, animated: false)
        }
        return true
    }

Comment: @IBAction func btn_openapp(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let mystring = "mydrop://" + String(campaign_id)
        self.extensionContext?.open(URL(string: mystring)!, completionHandler: nil)
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to add a stored property at the extension. If you need a stored property, in this case a button, you should create a UIView or UIViewController, according to your use case, and associate it to another UIView or UIViewController.

You should also try to share some code, because it is not clear about what you are asking for.